# I need to fetch all the content which has content settings and which doesn't

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm

I need to fetch all the content which has **content settings** and which **doesn't**, using both the includes methods. There is an association in the contentSetting table with the content_id and editor type.

I had done it with left outer join earlier but I have to do it with includes.

```
contents = Content.all
contents = contents
  .left_outer_joins(:content_setting)
  .where('content_settings.editor_type = ? OR content_settings.id IS NULL', '0')
```

but I want to perform this query using includes method.

Comment: @dbugger I had done it with left outer join earlier but I have to do it with includes.

Comment: Why do you have to use includes?

Comment: Content.includes(:content_setting).where(content_settings: {editor_type: [0,nil]})
Can't we do it? Some of your insights in this query 

@spickermann

Answer (score 1):

I think [`references`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-references) should help in this case:

```
Content
  .includes(:content_setting)
  .references(:content_settings)
  .where('content_settings.editor_type = ? OR content_settings.id IS NULL', '0')
```

Comment: Hi @spickermann Is there any other way without references I tried this but it is not working

Comment: Is not working is not a good error description. What happened instead? Was there an error message? What did it say?

Answer (score 0):

```rb
baseq = Content.includes(:content_setting)
baseq.where.missing(:bars).or(baseq.where(content_settings: { editor_type: 0 }))
```

Comment: Hi @smathy, the query you sent is indeed working, but the execution time is more than 3.6ms. Is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: To optimize it we need to know what indexes you have defined on the tables already and how many records those tables have.

Comment: @USER the thing to do here in SO is to accept this answer for this question, then ask a new question about optimization following the same process you did here (ie. clear question, as much detail as you think is needed, show what you tried, etc)